# Mysql listing from 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL databases

**1 for ads**

```
id | title  | date
```

======================

```
1    title1   date 1

2    title2   date 2

3    title3   date 3

4    title4   date 4

5    title 5  date 5
```

**and 1 for ads_packs**

```
id  | id_pack | id_ad
```

========================

```
1       1         1

2       2         2 

3       2         4
```

Well I need to list ads ordered by putting first the ads with id_pack2 and then list the other ads ordered by date.

Comment: Can you show a sample output? It would be helpful for we're not able to understand your question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join the tables and then order by a boolean expression that checks if the id_pack is equal to 2. We reverse the logic here as the false case (0) will be ordered first.

```
SELECT *
FROM ads a
   JOIN ads_packs p ON p.id_ad = a.id
ORDER BY p.id_pack <> 2, a.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ads.*, ads_packs.id_pack FROM ads
    INNER JOIN ads_packs ON ads.id = ads_packs.ad_id
WHERE ads_pack.id_pack = 2
ORDER BY ads.date DESC
```

Should give you the row from ads, with the pack id (extra) where the id_pack is 2, ordered by the most recent.